# Webform onchange added with hook_form_id_alter()

Tags: javascript, hooks, webforms

I have a webform on a Drupal 7 site I am working on whose form ID is 144. I have a module that alters this form to add default values to the webform fields. This works fine. I now have to add an `onchange` event to one of the text-fields.

This is the code I am trying in the module to add the event.

```php
$form['submitted']['postal_code']['#attributes']['onchange'] = 'getaddress(this)';
```

I have the *webform-form-144.tpl.php* template in the theme directory.

At the bottom of this template, I have the following the following line, to add the file containing the event handler.

```php
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/js/webform144.js');
```

At the moment all I have in the file is the following code.

```javascript
function getaddress(code) {
    alert(code);
}
```

The textfield rendering output is the following.

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="128" size="64" value="408600" name="submitted[postal_code]" id="edit-submitted-postal-code" class="form-control form-text required" onchange="getaddress(this)" required="required">
```

To me, this means `getaddress()` should be called with the current field value, when the `onchange` event is fired.

I cleared the cache. When I try to change anything in the postal_code field, nothing is happening; it looks like the `onchange` event is not fired. I am using the Firefox console and I am seeing no evidence of the `onchange` event being fired. I am also not seeing the output of `alert()`.

Am I missing something obvious?

This is the first time I tried to add an event to a webform field. I didn't find any example or tutorial.

Comment: if you want to take any value of form use "form_state" instead of "form" after that you can  check it

Comment: Can you confirm your js is loaded? Also, it would be nicer if you'd attach your js to the form, like this: `$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() .'/js/webform144.js');`

Comment: I think there is a module that can do the trick, maybe you should try it:
https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation

Comment: `this` never means a value. `this` always means an object. In this case, `this` means the `input` object. So, in `getaddress()`, you must have `alert(code.value);`.